# How to create a datepicker to the bottom in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

What I'm trying to approach is when user clicks on a button, a datepicker will show up at the bottom of screen. This is what I currently have but datepicker is taking the entire screen and shown as a popover.

```
VStack {
    Text("Birthdate").padding()
    Button(action: {
        self.showSheet = true
    }) {
        Text(startDate.toMediumString())
    }
    .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet){
        DatePicker("", selection: self.$startDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
            .labelsHidden()
    }
}
```

This is what I want to do.
[image]

or this is even better if there's already a built in component I can use.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry no chance to check. But i did something this

```
VStack {
Text("Birthdate").padding()
Button(action: {
    self.showSheet = true
}) {
    Text(startDate.toMediumString())
}
...

Spacer(minLength: 120)
if (self.showSheet == true){
    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
        DatePicker("", selection: self.$startDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        }
    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: 30, leading: 40, bottom: 120, trailing: 50)).background(Color.gray.opacity(0.1))
}
}
```

Comment: it works! thanks. but this looks more like custom way of putting datepicker. Is there a way to do summon generic datepicker with done button attached to it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59990555/swiftui-how-to-add-done-button-to-picker would help you

Comment: so it sounds like theres no default datepicker I can use to achieve the same. thanks